# iOS 7 - no provisioned ios devices are available

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios7, xcode5

I have installed iOS 7 on my iPhone 5 and the Beta Version of Xcode 5 on my mac.

When I want to run an app on my iPhone, Xcode says:

"no provisioned ios devices are available with a compatible iOS version"

What went wrong?

Comment: Have you set deployment target compatible with your device? Also check Base SDK used.

Comment: You will get better help on the Apple Developer Forums, since this is a beta version of iOS which is under NDA, you shouldn't discuss it in public. There is a forum section just for this over on the Apple Developer Forums.

Comment: For anyone who wishes to down or close vote due to NDA, please see: [Should moderators enforce NDAs for software vendors?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/94465) and related questions. It is not SO's policy, responsibility, or concern to enforce or police NDAs between other parties.

Comment: However, this does seem quite likely to be a duplicate.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's a guess. But if you have installed IOS7 on your device.

You need to say again that you want to use it for development. You can do this in the organizer --> devices in xcode

Comment: Also wait till Xcode identifies your device. Otherwise restart xcode

Comment: Where do I open this "organizer"?

Comment: Window --> organizer

Answer (score 0):

Go to project and Target Settings and Make sure that you have set the right provisioning profile before running it on your device. As you are mentioning that you have installed a new SDK and Xcode, i would suggest you to check the provisioning profile once again.